# PHP-FPM exec results different from commandline

Tags: php, shell

I'm facing a strange problem : I have a PHP script doing this

```
<?php exec('sudo /bin/ps aux', $output, $retval) ?>
<pre><?php print_r($output); ?></pre>
<?php echo $retval; ?>
```

The /bin/ps command is permitted to be launched vith sudo  (/etc/sudoers) :

```
tv25  xxxxxx.ovh.net=(root) NOPASSWD:/bin/ps
```

This is a very simple script, (verify that some processes launched as root are still running) but I have 2 differents outputs depending on my environment :

1. If i log in to the system with the user tv25 and launch the script (php script.php) from command line, exrything works as expected.
2. If I launch the script as a page (Apache + PHP-FPM, running as user tv25), $ouput is an empty array, and $retval equals 1.

I have tried to indicate the full path of ps , of sudo, but it does works. Tried to prefix the command with a valid shell (/bin/sh), but doesn't solve.

Forinformation, the exec function is allowed in my php.ini.

Thanks for your help,

Jérémie

Comment: Did you try to use shell_exec?

Comment: Well, I tested every possible function to execute external scripts...

Answer (score 0):

Try taking off the sudo (worked for me), you should have it running by simply doing as follows:

```
<?php exec('ps aux', $output, $retval); ?>
<pre><?php print_r($output); ?></pre>
<?php echo $retval; ?>
```